# Upload multiplo de arquivos em PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, upload

sou iniciante em PHP e estou desenvolvendo um sistema para uma imobiliária. O importuno que me ocorreu foi o seguinte: Preciso fazer upload de 20 fotos de um imóvel utilizando apenas 1 input e salvar o nome do arquivo no banco. Consigo fazer o upload dos arquivos e redimensioná-los perfeitamente, porém estou com problemas para salvar na tabela o nome de cada imagem separadamente. Por exemplo, consigo interpretar a imagem e renomeá-la porém a primeira imagem deve ficar na coluna "foto1" enquanto a segunda na coluna "foto2", porém não encontrei função para interpretar cada arquivo separadamente, então todas as colunas recebem o valor apenas do último arquivo selecionado no input multiple.

Versão reduzida do código:

```
 <html>
   <body>
     <form action="#" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="fileUpload[]" multiple>
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
     </form>
  </body>
 </html>

  <?php
     if(isset($_FILES['fileUpload']))
     {
        require 'WideImage/WideImage.php'; 

        date_default_timezone_set("Brazil/East");

        $name   = $_FILES['fileUpload']['name']; 
        $tmp_name = $_FILES['fileUpload']['tmp_name']; 

        $allowedExts = array(".gif", ".jpeg", ".jpg", ".png", ".bmp"); 

        $dir = 'uploads/';

        for($i = 0; $i < count($tmp_name); $i++) 
        {
           $ext = strtolower(substr($name[$i],-4));

           if(in_array($ext, $allowedExts)) 
           {
              $new_name = date("Y.m.d-H.i.s") ."-". $i . $ext;

              $image = WideImage::load($tmp_name[$i]); 

              $image = $image->resize(170, 180, 'outside'); 

              $image = $image->crop('center', 'center', 170, 180); 

              $image->saveToFile($dir.$new_name); 

              $sql = "INSERT INTO imoveis (foto1) VALUES ('$new_name')";
              $result = mysql_query($sql) or die('Erro ao executar instrucao SQL :-( ERRO->'.mysql_error());
           }
        }
     }
  ?>
```

Comment: Poste o código que você tem para lhe ajudarmos melhor :)

Comment: Ola, você diz que consegue fazer upload das 20 fotos em questão e até mesmo renomear, para isso você deve está usando um LOOP para acessa as X fotos, o que você pode fazer é inserir as fotos no BD no mesmo LOOP que você faz upload das fotos ou guarda o caminho da foto em um ARRAY e criar um novo LOOP para acessa esse array e fazer inset no BD. Por que você não posta o código em questão?.

Comment: Adicionei o código à pergunta Lucas!

Comment: Com a sua dica adicionei o INSERT INTO no loop e consegui efetuar a inserção de um valor na tabela Lucas! Agora a questão é: Como dar continuidade fazendo com que a segunda foto fique na coluna foto2 da tabela e assim sucessivamente?